# Ways to import specific csv-columns into postgres-db with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm a little confused about the amount of possibilities to import csv-data into a postgres database.

My issue: I have a csv-file with about 70 columns, but I only want to import specific columns of these 70.

I've tried the `psycopg2.copy_from()`, but when I specify my columns like this:

```
psycopg2.copy_from(csv_in, 'stamm_data', sep=';', columns = 'col_1', 'col_4', 'col_7')
```

I get:

```
Error: extra data after last expected column
```

So, another solution is to work with `dictionaries` with the column-name as key, the data as value and then import the data with `psycopg2.execute("INSERT INTO..")` into the database.

I also could write my needed columns into a new csv-file and import it with `psycopg2.copy_from()`.

Or I use `psycopg2.execute("COPY ..")` or `psycopg2.copy_expert()`.

So, whats the most effective way for my issue?

Comment: You need to pass an iterable `['col_1','col_4','col_7']` - and I do not think you can select individual columns like that (from the documentation): _"**The length and types should match the content of the file to read.** If not specified, it is assumed that the entire table matches the file structure."_ but try with the iterable first.

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't work - I get the same Error as I mentioned above. When column-option isn't for picking up individual columns, then I don't get the sense behind this option. The documentation sound like this option is for picking up individual columns imho.

Comment: I believe the `columns` option is for enumerating which columns in your already-created database table will receive the data imported from the file.  For example, if you are importing this data into a table with 90 columns, you would need this option to specify which 70 are going to be populated.  Since `copy_from` is a wrapper around the native PostgreSQL `COPY` functionality, it probably can't do anything short of importing the entirety of each row it encounters.